# GitHub Action Configuration for Pyproject.toml in Subfolder

Tags: python, pytest, github-actions

I am trying to get my Pytests running on pushes to my repository.  The issue I am facing is that I have my *pyproject.toml* file in the subfolder app and not in the root directory. How can I move to the foler app before the step *Install dependencies*? I hope this would fix the issues.

This is my GitHub Action workflow.yaml file:

```
# .github/workflows/app.yaml
name: PyTest
on: push

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Switch to Current Branch
        run: git checkout ${{ env.BRANCH }}

      # Setup Python (faster than using Python container)
      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: "3.x"

      # install & configure poetry
      - name: Install Poetry
        uses: snok/install-poetry@v1
        with:
          virtualenvs-create: true
          virtualenvs-in-project: true
          installer-parallel: true

      # load cached venv if cache exists
      - name: Load cached venv
        id: cached-poetry-dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: .venv
          key: venv-${{ runner.os }}-${{ steps.setup-python.outputs.python-version }}-${{ hashFiles('**/poetry.lock') }}

      # install dependencies if cache does not exist
      - name: Install dependencies
        if: steps.cached-poetry-dependencies.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: poetry install --no-interaction --no-root

      # install root project
      - name: Install project
        run: poetry install --no-interaction

      # run test suite
      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          export PYTHONPATH=$PWD
          poetry run pytest -v -cov=pp_from_python
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `poetry install -C {pyproject_yaml_directory} --no-interaction --no-root`

Comment: Thanks @ozs! 'poetry install -C back' made the poetry install work. However, I encountered the issue that during the last section with the 'poetry run pytest', the command pytest was not found. I instead did a 'cd back' before each poetry install, which made poetry run find pytest. Possibly there is another way to do this, but at least it is working now. Thanks again!

Comment: thank you for your comment. the -C can be added also in 'poetry run' which might also fix the issue